# How to add user defined objects to LinkedList?

Tags: java, object, linked-list, user-defined-functions

I am trying to add my user defined objects to a linked list however every time I add, the information just gets duplicated.

```
public class Videostore(){
    public LinkedList<Video> videoList = new LinkedList<>();
    public Videostore(){
        addVideo("a");
        addVideo("b");
        addVideo("c");
    }
    private void addVideo(String o){  
        Video vid = new Video(o);
        videoList.add(vid);     
    }
}

public class Video {

    public static Object title;
    public static boolean isRent;

    public Video(String t){
        title = t;
        isRent = false;
    }

    public static void setisRent(boolean bool){
        isRent = bool;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return title.toString();
    }
}
```

When Video Store is initialized the videoList has only "c"'s inside.I need it to have a b and c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `Video` class variables are `static`, meaning only one copy of each for the whole class.  They get overwritten with each new instance.

```
Video ---> "c"
         ^ ^
Video --/ /
         /
Video --/
```

Remove `static` to make them instance variables, meaning one each per instance of the class.  Then the values won't overwrite each other.

```
Video ---> "a"

Video ---> "b"

Video ---> "c"
```